# Build passes in maven, but fails under sonar

Tags: hibernate, junit, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

i am using sonarqube version: 4.3
my java plugin version: 2.3
jacoco version: 0.7.1

there are some tests that pass in maven normal build but fails under sonar, jacoco.

for example:

```
 Error Message

 No row with the given identifier exists:[com.project.hibernate.entity.DummyProperty#30]
 Stacktrace

 org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.project.hibernate.entity.DummyProperty#30]
```

how can i solve this issue? Is it possible that jacoco has problems with hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says your are trying to retrieve an non existent entity by it's id.
Check your environment and your test code; how is this entity supposed to be available? It seems you sometimes have this entity and sometimes don't.